# .htaccess rewrite rule for unknown variables

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a URL in the following format:

```
http://example.com/auction/lot/0001/
```

Where **1** is the SKU of the product in question.

I would like to setup a rewrite rule where anyone visiting **/auction/lot/1/** is redirected to the **0001** version.

What I can't get my head around is working out the number of **0's**.

For example an SKU of **150** would mean someone visiting **/auction/lot/150** would need to be directed to **/auction/lots/0150** where as an SKU of **3016** would remain the same for both.

Does anyone know how to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^auction/lot/([0-9]{1,3})/?$ auction/lot/0$1/ [N,L]
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the .htaccess in your document root

```
RewriteRule auction/lot/(\d{1,3})/ auction/lot/000$1/ [L,QSA]
RewriteRule auction/lot/.*(\d{4})/ auction/lot/$1/ [R=301,L]
```